# Can I leave Kuwait with a new passport and a tourist visa with different names

Tags: visas, uk-citizens, passport-renewals, kuwait

I am in Kuwait on a tourist visa and my visa is in my maiden name. I have a new passport in my married name but I entered Kuwait with a tourist visa in my maiden name. Will I have any problems leaving Kuwait in June?

Comment: Why would you want to switch passport with different names smack in the middle of a trip? Immigration doesn't like that, they like trace-ability particularly in this time of terror. Unless of course you got married in Kuwait and did the name change, otherwise it smacks of some attempt to **mislead**. It will be better you exit with your original passport and start using your new passport/name as you are entering the next country.

Comment: @SheikPaul You're sounding pretty hysterical there. People get married and change passports all the time: show both passports, no problem.

Comment: Yes but am on a tourist visa and I am in kuwait. I do have all my uk documents and old and new passport

Answer (score 3):

**You'll be fine**.  Just bring both passports with you and show them at check-in and to immigration.  Bringing a marriage/name change certificate won't hurt.

Note that I'm assuming your old passport is expired/cancelled now.  If it's still valid, then you don't even need to show them the new one, although the airline may still want to see it due to passport validity rules at your destination.

Comment: You're providing very wrong advice which can get OP in trouble. Hers does not sound like the simple case of getting married and getting a new passport. Read it again. It sounds like she had a new passport all along, chose to travel on the old one with her visa, and once at her destination attempting to exit on the new one for some unexplained reason. If that is the case, it can be construed as an attempt to mislead.

Comment: @SheikPaulofOsawatomie What is "misleading" about *presenting both passports*?  "Here's the old passport I came in with, here's the new one, here's the reason I changed my name."

Comment: I didn't have my new passport when I traveled. I would never do that. I had applied for new passport while I am in kuwait helping my husband to pack . I am not misleading anyone . I have all my uk documents and old and new passport with me

Comment: @Tracey If this answered your question, please click the check mark to accept it!